# Do all currently supported Ubuntu releases have the same version of Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel

Do currently supported Ubuntu release (such as 12.04, 14.04, 14.10, 15.04) have the same versions of Linux Kernel?
Or older Ubuntu releases may not have as recent Linux kernel as newer Ubuntu releases?

If they have the same versions of Linux Kernel, what are the defining factors of distinguishing the Ubuntu releases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Different Ubuntu releases have different kernel versions. Here are links to the 2 most recent kernels for 12.04 and 14.04:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image-3.8.0-44-generic

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic

The current "stable" kernel from kernel.org is 3.19.4.

Stable releases especially run slightly older kernels. Each kernel version needs time to get really stable (although some are better than the others).

Changing kernels is rarely done on a stable release. Often some low-level tools depend on certain kernel features and changing the kernel would break these tools.

Comment: well, the ubuntu kernel is also patched, so it takes time to test and if necessary configure the patches. Fedora runs a more up to date kernel `uname -r 3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64` without kernel stability issues. For these reasons I am downvoting your answer.

Comment: See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: According to kernel.org, latest stable is 4.0 - https://www.kernel.org/ . Fedora 22 runs a 4.0 kernel ;)